# IF statement doesn't work with TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, xml, textwatcher, android-textwatcher

My code looks simple and I don't know what is the problem. If I code something like this:

```
tvResult.setText(sum+ "RUB");
```

it shows correct numbers. But if I try to add an IF statement like this:

```
if(sum>=114000) {
                    tvResult.setText(sum + " RUB");
                }
```

and sum equals, say, 1000000, it shows weird number: 1111111.0. Need your advice =) Thanks in advance

Here is the XML code:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvCash"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvCalculate"
        android:hint="@string/cash_money"
        android:background="@drawable/zakat_red"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/etCash"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tvBank"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="@string/hint_zakat"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

And Java code:

```
TextWatcher twCash=new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                tvCash.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zakat_green);
                sum+=Float.valueOf(etCash.getText().toString());
                if(sum>=114000) {
                    tvResult.setText(sum + " RUB");
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: You mean to say that if you remove if(sum>=114000) , then you don't see decimals in 'tvResult' ?

Comment: no. If I remove if(sum>=114000) then it shows correct numbers. But I need that statement for future use. With that statement it shows incorrect numbers. If the sum==1000000, it says that sum==1111111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with your logic. As you are using `TextWatcher`, to compute the sum of all the numbers entered in your `editText`, even if you type '.'  after any number , `afterTextChanged()` will get invoked and then it will add that number to the aggregated sum.So let's say , you input the following characters consecutively :  2 , 3, . , 4 , 7 
Then you will get the sum =  94.87
And I guess this is not the correct way to compute the sum of the numbers entered.
You have to correct your logic to get the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand =) The variable calls sum, but in this example it doesn't make any additions(It will be in advance. I simplified the example because the problem isn't in calculations, it is in IF statement). I just want to display the input number on tvResult if it is more than 114000. When I input 1000000 it shows 1111111 if I use an IF statement and it shows correct numbers if I don't use it. The IF statement changes something...

Comment: Please add logs immediately before the if condition and inside the if condition - Log.d("debug","SUM::" + sum); and check whether they depict the same values or different.

Comment: Yes, it is different. It adds one additional 1 to each input number =) I understood what you said about aggregations. Seems like the problem isn't in the IF statement and I misunderstood how to use TextWatcher =) Thanks for your help!

Comment: I upvoted, but it will be displayed later when I get more reputation =)

Answer (score 0):

The ".0" is most likely coming up because the sum variable is a float or something. You should either use an int for the variable sum, or you should cast it to an int when you are displaying it. This should work.

```
if (sum >= 114000) {
    tvResult.setText((int)sum + " RUB");
}
```

If you need it to be a sum and only show the values after the decimal if they aren't zero, you'll need to write a method to parse the value to return what you want.

Comment: Now it shows 1111111, without .0 =) Instead of 1000000